# Julia - Adding rows/columns to sparse matrices

Tags: insert, julia, sparse-matrix

Is there a quick way to add columns/rows to sparse matrices?

```
a = sparse([1,2],[1,2],[1,1])
2x2 sparse matrix with 2 Int64 entries:
[1, 1]  =  1
[2, 2]  =  1
```

how could I add f.x

```
a[3,3] = 1
```

without pulling out every value and reinitializing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Julia's regular concatenation features for matrices, e.g.

```
julia> a = sparse([1,2],[1,2],[1,1])
2x2 sparse matrix with 2 Int64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  1
    [2, 2]  =  1

julia> b = sparse([0 0])
1x2 sparse matrix with 0 Int64 entries:

julia> c = sparse([0 ; 0 ; 1])
3x1 sparse matrix with 1 Int64 entries:
    [3, 1]  =  1

julia> d = [[a ; b] c]
3x3 sparse matrix with 3 Int64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  1
    [2, 2]  =  1
    [3, 3]  =  1

julia> full(d)
3x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0
 0  1  0
 0  0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another "rogue" (but faster) way to get the same results, is by defining the following function:

```
function Base.resize!{T,D}(sp::SparseMatrixCSC{T,D},m,n)
  newcolptr = sp.colptr
  resize!(newcolptr,n+1)
  for i=sp.n+2:n+1
    newcolptr[i] = sp.colptr[sp.n+1] 
  end
  return SparseMatrixCSC(m,n,newcolptr,sp.rowval,sp.nzval)
end
```

To use the function for the problem in the OP:

```
a = sparse([1,2],[1,2],[1,1])
a = resize!(a,3,3)
a[3,3] = 1
```

This solution is "rogue" because it doesn't actually change `a` but forgets `a` and rebinds it to a new sparse matrix. This is necessary because sparse matrices are immutable. If you keep both `a` and the return value of `resize!` both will share buffers in memory and bad things can happen. On the positive side, it should be very quick and the usage example above leaves no dangers.

P.S. Maybe overloading `resize!` is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `blockdiag` as [image]