# Is it possible to reshape a sparse array in Julia?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I'm attempting to reshape a sparse array in Julia, but get errors while doing so. Is it even possible? And if so, how?

Some snapshots of frustration:

```
julia> A = sparse([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64} with 3 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  1
  [2, 2]  =  2
  [3, 3]  =  3

julia> reshape(A, (5, 5))
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("parent has 9 elements, which is incompatible with size (5, 5)")
Stacktrace:
```

```
julia> A.m
3

julia> A.m = 4
ERROR: setfield! immutable struct of type SparseMatrixCSC cannot be changed
Stacktrace:
```

```
julia> J = Base.ReshapedArray(A, (4, 4), ())
4×4 reshape(::SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64}, 4, 4) with eltype Int64:
 1  2    3     #undef
 0  0  #undef  #undef
 0  0  #undef  #undef
 0  0  #undef  #undef

julia> J[4, 4] = 4
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64} at index [1, 6]
Stacktrace:
```

I also tried `resize!(A, 4*4)`, but nothing seems to work. Again, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Edit: I should've been more clear, I want to resize the array specifically to add more elements outside the 3x3 range (in the example code). Like `A[4, 4] = 1` doesn't currently work.

Comment: What outcome are you expecting when you are reshaping a matrix with `n` elements into a matrix with a different number of elements? The idea of `reshape` is not to change but to move elements, so e.g. `reshape(A, 9, 1)` works

Comment: I've updated my question to show what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017242/julia-adding-rows-columns-to-sparse-matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new sparse array with

```
julia> i, j, v = findnz(A)
([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

julia> sparse(i, j, v, 5, 5)
5×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64, Int64} with 3 stored entries:
 1  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  3  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
```

The inverse of `sparse` is `findnz`, which retrieves the inputs used to create the sparse array. See the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/).

(Edit, just to note that my output is different from yours because I used Julia v1.6 (release candidate 1 or `rc1` at the time of writing), which has this cool new `show` methods for sparse matrices.)